# Who or Whom? Which is the right one here?

Tags: pronouns

I read this sentence:

> "One of the women whom dislikes me made it"

I was wondering whether 'whom' is the right word in the sentence above or it should have been "who". I think "who" is the right one. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sentence should read

> One of the women who dislikes me made it.

but before I go any further, I should note that the usage of *whom* has been in [steady](http://www.economist.com/blogs/johnson/2012/04/grammar) [decline](http://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/2013/04/for-whom-the-bell-tolls/309266/) for some time, and especially in conversational English, *who* is the expected 
form everywhere. When in doubt, simply use *who*; only the more persnickety prescriptivists will object.

*Who* is the nominative case form and *whom* is the objective (accusative) case form. A very basic "ear test" is to separate out the clause on its own and replace *who* with *he* or *she*, and *whom* with *him* or *her*. We would say *she dislikes me* not *her dislikes me*, and so *whom* is improper here.

The grammatical reason why *who* is correct is that it is the subject of the clause, and therefore must be in the nominative case. Substituting *whom* for *who* is a very common hypercorrection even among native speakers, but has no justification.

Comment: Yes, I know that whom is 'dying' and, as you said, 'who' is the expected form everywhere, but considering that the sentence above comes from an English mother tongue I needed to get a confirmation. I think he could also have written "One of the women that dislikes me made it".

Comment: [This post on Language Log by Arnold Zwicky](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/004084.html) is worth reading.  Among other things, it covers some of the cases (ahem) where *who/whom* don't line up with *he/him*, *she/her*, etc.

Comment: "hypercorrection" Like those who think they're being correct when they use "I" in the object instead of "me", like, "He gave the book to Bill and I." Exactly the same case: "who" and "I" are for subjects; "whom" and "me" for objects.

Comment: @Jay I'm afraid it's not actually the same. Neither *Bill* nor *I* is an object; the coordination of the two is an object. This matters because the rules for pronouns in coordination in some cases are different than the rules for pronouns used as subjects or objects, so an argument by analogy to non-coordinated objects isn't logically sound.  On top of that, *who* and *whom* don't have the same distribution as *I* and *me*, so the analogy wouldn't hold even if the above were false.

Comment: @snailboat Hmm, can you give an example where a word that when used as an object by itself takes one form, but when used in combination with another word takes a different form?